# feign : com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: xxx

Tags: spring-cloud-feign

I have some problem with using spring cloud feign:
when I use these codes it works well,

```
@Service
@FeignClient(name = "MS-ASSET-SECURITYTEST",value="MS-ASSET-SECURITYTEST" ,fallback = AssetServiceFallback.class, url="http://192.168.66.158:8066"))
public interface AssetService {
xxxxxxx
}
```

but when I change the code like this, when i call the method of this feignclient, it will report an exception :

> com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have
>   available server for client: xxx

```
@Service
@FeignClient(value = "MS-ASSET-SECURITYTEST", fallback = AssetServiceFallback.class))
public interface AssetService {
xxx
}
```

heres the full infomation of the exception :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client:
>   MS-ASSET-SECURITYTEST
>         at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:71)
>         at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:97)
>         at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
>         at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108)
>         at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)
>         at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
>         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
>         at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)
>         at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47)
>         at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69)
>         at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: MS-ASSET-SECURITYTEST
>         at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483)
>         at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184)
>         at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180)
>         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)
>         at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127)
>         at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73)
>         at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45)
>         at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)
>         at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)
>         at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138)
>         at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307)
>         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274)
>         at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:445)
>         at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342)
>         at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:117)
>         at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:63)
>         ... 32 common frames omitted

I have try to change the config, but it done's make any sense.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this @juwuba?

Comment: yes, at localhost , you should add the url like this: @FeignClient(name = "MS-ASSET-SECURITYTEST",value="MS-ASSET-SECURITYTEST" ,fallback = AssetServiceFallback.class, url="http://192.168.66.158:8066"))
when you deploy your app on your server, you can remove this :url="http://192.168.66.158:8066"

Comment: In my case, I have replaced my localhost with `127.0.0.1:8763` to make it working @juwuba